# How to point testCafe to executable startup file

Tags: reactjs, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I can't figure out why (or if it's not allowed) testcafe won't run my runner class file.
Current setup

#### package.json:

```
{
...
 "test:integration": "testcafe ./bin/integration.js",
...
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "testcafe": "^1.5.0",
    "testcafe-react-selectors": "^3.2.0",
    ...
}
```

#### bin/integration.js (bin on level of package.json)

```
const createTestCafe = require('testcafe')
let runner = null
let testcafe = null

createTestCafe('localhost', 1337, 1338)
  .then(tc => {
    testcafe = tc
    runner = testcafe.createRunner()

    return testcafe.createBrowserConnection()
  })
  .then(remoteConnection => {
    // Outputs remoteConnection.url so that it can be visited from the remote browser.
    console.log('remote url:', remoteConnection.url)
    remoteConnection.once('ready', () => {
      runner
        .src('../integration-tests/*test.js*')
        .browsers(['chrome'])
        .run({
          selectorTimeout: 50000,
          assertionTimeout: 7000,
          pageLoadTimeout: 8000
        })
        .then(failed => {
          console.log('failed tests:', failed)
          testcafe.close()
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error)
        })
    })
  })
```

Error received:
`ERROR Unable to find the browser. "./bin/integration.js" is not a browser alias or path to an executable file.`

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand, you want to use the testcafe API to run your tests. In this case, you do not need to start tests using the `testcafe` command.

The `testcafe` command usually expects at least two arguments: `browsers` and `sources`. When you use the `testcafe ./bin/integration.js` command, the CLI arguments parser processes the argument as a browser alias, so you see the error.

I suppose that you need to run your script with the following command: `node ./bin/integration.js`

Comment: Thanks so much, looks like this mostly works (doesn't auto launch the browser, but if I click on the link I log from the runner file, it does). Follow up question if I may, how do I reference the base url generated by the remoteConnection in my tests? 
For example, it generates a remote url of http://localhost:1337/browser/connect/OPRoJCO, the last / followed by a unique id. How do I reference that base url in all of my `.src('./integration-tests/*test.ts*')` 's?
Much appreciated

Comment: At first, you need to pass the remote connection to the 'browsers' method: `.browsers([remoteConnection, 'chrome'])`. Second, you do not need to pass remoteConnection's URL to the test files. This URL should be visited from a remote browser in order to connect it to the TestCafe server.